# Могу ли я публиковать похожие приложения в appStore?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, appstore

Я хочу публиковать приложения для фитнес-клубов. Пройдут ли приложения ревью, если я буду менять в них дизайн и бренд?

Comment: могут и не пройти. читаем определение `Repeated submission of similar apps`. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/#common-app-rejections

Answer (score 0):

Из практики даже первое приложение могут отклонить с требованием публикации с аккаунта клуба для которого сделано это приложение.
Не помогут даже апелляции с подтверждением, что приложение сделано для них на заказ и т.п.